# Vagrant/Homestead ssh Identity file not accessible: no such file or directory

Tags: laravel, ssh, vagrant, homestead

I'm having an issue when trying to run

```
vagrant ssh
```

I keep getting

```
Warning: Identity file C:/Users/Firstnamenot accessible: No such file or directory.
bash: Lastname/Homestead/.vagrant/machines/homestead-7/virtualbox/private_key: No such file or directory
```

I normally try to stick to one word usernames, but work set this computer so I'm stuck with that space there. At least I'm guessing that the command is seeing the space and thinking that's the end of the directory path. Is there a way to hard code this path, or a way around it?

Edit:
I'm running on windows

and my homestead.yaml is:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

 authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

 keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

 sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Comment: What do you have in `Homestead.yaml`?

Comment: I'm stuck here with the same problem that there are spaces in my path names.

Comment: Just the defaults so far.
I've tried to hardcode the ~ to:

C:/Users/Firstname Lastname/

That doesn't seem to have any effect after running 

    vagrant reload --provision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install homestead again in a different directory, to do so I followed 
[Change VAGRANT_HOME directory on windows](https://harvsworld.com/2014/change-vagrant_home-directory-windows/)

```
setx VAGRANT_HOME="X:\your\path"
```

Then as indicated at the manual I created the box again

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

I also created a Homestead dir outside my users folder and follow the manual:

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
git chechout vX.Y.Z
bash init.sh
```

So if you can make directories outside your user directory, this should work.